# Byte.decode("10") and Byte.valueOf("10") - what is a difference?

Tags: java, wrapper

Java 6 API primitive type wrappers have pairs of static methods **decode(String s)** and **valueOf(String s)**. Both of them return a new object of wrapper class type and none of them are annotated as deprecated. Does someone know the difference between them? For example:

```
Byte b1 = Byte.decode("10");
```

and

```
Byte b2 = Byte.valueOf("10");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), `valueOf` only takes Strings that can be interpreted as signed decimal values, while `decode` takes decimal, hex, or octal Strings (prefixed by 0x, #, or 0) - though `valueOf` is overloaded to also take the radix explicitly.

Comment: this gives 'funny' results, like parsing 0-padded values '09'

Comment: Not so funny if you know that a leading 0 indicates an octal string.

Comment: 0-padded indicates an octal, as defined by the Java language specification.

Comment: i know that, but we had problems with a propiarity format, witch was decimal and 0 padded. the xml framework we used while converting used decode, which resulted in errors...

Comment: @Salandur - that is a bug in the XML framework you are using, or in the way that you are using.  The `decode` method is working as specified.  You (or the XML framework developers) should not have assumed that `decode` and `valueOf` work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

The decode method allows you to specify the radix (hex, octal) in the string itself using "0x", "0X" or "#" for hex and "0" as a prefix for octal numbers, while valueOf allows you to pass the radix as a number (e.g. 8 or 16) as an optional parameter. decode("0x10") is equivalent to valueOf("10", 16). Your example valueOf("0x10") will fail with a NumberFormatException.